# Developing Carddav/Caldav Server. Events disappear clientside on iOS after syncing

Tags: ios, calendar, webdav, caldav

I am currently developing a carddav / caldav server. I can already communicate with lots of clients on windows / windows phone / android. Now I tryed syncing with iOS. Addressbook syncing works fine but the calendar app behaves strange. It syncs all the calendars and appointments and shows them correctly.It even links the participants in an event to the contact in the addressbook. But once syncing is finished, the calendars and appointments disappear completely. Anybody has a hint?

My testdevice is an IPad 2 with iOS 8.3 (12F69).

Here is the communication. I am leaving out the requests without Authorization Header. Also i had to edit the hostname but it is the same during all requests.

I don't answer a lot of the properties iOS asks. But since all appointments show correctly during a short time, these shouldn't be needed. Also a lot of them are not part of the caldav specification (but still placed in the same xmlns?).

## Initial Propfind

### Request

```
PROPFIND host:9998/.well-known/caldav HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) accountsd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic ZmdoZ2poZ2g6a2dmZ2hqaA==
Content-Length: 181
Brief: t

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <A:current-user-principal/>
    <A:principal-URL/>
    <A:resourcetype/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 791
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:22 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
        <d:current-user-principal>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:current-user-principal>
        <d:principal-url>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:principal-url>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## Options

### Request

```
OPTIONS http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Language: de-de
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) accountsd/1.0
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:22 GMT
```

## Propfind (I don't answer a lot of properties here)

### Request

```
PROPFIND host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Content-Length: 743
Brief: t
```

```
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <B:calendar-home-set xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <B:calendar-user-address-set xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <A:current-user-principal/>
    <A:displayname/>
    <C:dropbox-home-URL xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:email-address-set xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:notification-URL xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <A:principal-collection-set/>
    <A:principal-URL/>
    <A:resource-id/>
    <B:schedule-inbox-URL xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <B:schedule-outbox-URL xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <A:supported-report-set/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 958
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:48 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:displayname>Robert Glaser</d:displayname>
        <d:current-user-principal>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:current-user-principal>
        <cal:calendar-home-set>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </cal:calendar-home-set>
        <d:principal-url>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:principal-url>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## Propfind

### Request

```
PROPFIND http://host:9998/.well-known/carddav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic Z2poZ2o6amhqamo=
Content-Length: 439
Brief: t

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <D:addressbook-home-set xmlns:D="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"/>
    <D:directory-gateway xmlns:D="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"/>
    <A:displayname/>
    <C:email-address-set xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <A:principal-collection-set/>
    <A:principal-URL/>
    <A:resource-id/>
    <A:supported-report-set/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 795
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:48 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/carddav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:displayname>Robert Glaser</d:displayname>
        <card:addressbook-home-set>
          <d:href>/.well-known/carddav/DEVELOPMENT/addressbooks/</d:href>
        </card:addressbook-home-set>
        <d:principal-url>
          <d:href>/.well-known/carddav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:principal-url>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## Propfind

### Request

```
PROPFIND http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Content-Length: 2097
Brief: t

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <A:add-member/>
    <C:allowed-sharing-modes xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <F:autoprovisioned xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"/>
    <E:bulk-requests xmlns:E="http://me.com/_namespace/"/>
    <F:calendar-color xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"/>
    <B:calendar-description xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <B:calendar-free-busy-set xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <F:calendar-order xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"/>
    <B:calendar-timezone xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <A:current-user-privilege-set/>
    <B:default-alarm-vevent-date xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <B:default-alarm-vevent-datetime xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <A:displayname/>
    <C:getctag xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <F:language-code xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"/>
    <F:location-code xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"/>
    <A:owner/>
    <C:pre-publish-url xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:publish-url xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:push-transports xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:pushkey xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <A:quota-available-bytes/>
    <A:quota-used-bytes/>
    <F:refreshrate xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"/>
    <A:resource-id/>
    <A:resourcetype/>
    <B:schedule-calendar-transp xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <B:schedule-default-calendar-URL xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <C:source xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:subscribed-strip-alarms xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:subscribed-strip-attachments xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:subscribed-strip-todos xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <B:supported-calendar-component-set xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <B:supported-calendar-component-sets xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <A:supported-report-set/>
    <A:sync-token/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 2984
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:49 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
        <cs:getctag/>
        <d:displayname>Robert Glaser</d:displayname>
        <d:current-user-privilege-set>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:all/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:read/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:read-acl/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:write/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:write-content/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:read-current-user-privilege-set/>
          </d:privilege>
        </d:current-user-privilege-set>
        <d:owner>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:owner>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
          <cal:calendar/>
        </d:resourcetype>
        <cs:getctag>669801837942</cs:getctag>
        <d:displayname>Alle Termine</d:displayname>
        <d:supported-report-set>
          <d:supported-report>
            <d:report>
              <cal:calendar-multiget/>
            </d:report>
          </d:supported-report>
          <d:supported-report>
            <d:report>
              <cal:calendar-query/>
            </d:report>
          </d:supported-report>
        </d:supported-report-set>
        <d:current-user-privilege-set>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:all/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:read/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:read-acl/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:write/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:write-content/>
          </d:privilege>
          <d:privilege>
            <d:read-current-user-privilege-set/>
          </d:privilege>
        </d:current-user-privilege-set>
        <cal:supported-calendar-component-set>
          <cal:comp name="VEVENT"/>
          <cal:comp name="VTIMEZONE"/>
        </cal:supported-calendar-component-set>
        <d:owner>
          <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
        </d:owner>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## Proppatch (not implemented

### Request

```
PROPPATCH http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Language: de-de
Content-Length: 198
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propertyupdate xmlns:A="DAV:"><A:set><A:prop><F:calendar-order xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">0</F:calendar-order></A:prop></A:set></A:propertyupdate>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1029
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:49 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.24 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 501 - </h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.24</h3></body></html>
```

## Propfind

### Request

```
PROPFIND http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Content-Length: 267
Brief: t

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <B:calendar-user-address-set xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"/>
    <A:displayname/>
    <C:email-address-set xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 500
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:49 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/principals/Robert%20Glaser/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:displayname>Robert Glaser</d:displayname>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## MKCALENDAR (not implemented)

### Request

```
MKCALENDAR http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/B39676BE-F124-475E-9ED2-B8756951DF29/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Language: de-de
Content-Length: 1046
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<B:mkcalendar xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
  <A:set xmlns:A="DAV:">
    <A:prop>
      <F:calendar-order xmlns:F="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">0</F:calendar-order>
      <B:calendar-timezone>BEGIN:VCALENDAR&#13;
VERSION:2.0&#13;
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN&#13;
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE&#13;
TZID:Europe/Berlin&#13;
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT&#13;
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100&#13;
TZNAME:MESZ&#13;
TZOFFSETTO:+0200&#13;
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU&#13;
DTSTART:19810329T020000&#13;
END:DAYLIGHT&#13;
BEGIN:STANDARD&#13;
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200&#13;
TZNAME:MEZ&#13;
TZOFFSETTO:+0100&#13;
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU&#13;
DTSTART:19961027T030000&#13;
END:STANDARD&#13;
END:VTIMEZONE&#13;
END:VCALENDAR&#13;
</B:calendar-timezone>
      <A:displayname>Erinnerungen</A:displayname>
      <B:calendar-free-busy-set>
        <NO/>
      </B:calendar-free-busy-set>
      <B:supported-calendar-component-set>
        <B:comp name="VTODO"/>
      </B:supported-calendar-component-set>
    </A:prop>
  </A:set>
</B:mkcalendar>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1029
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:49 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.24 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 501 - </h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.24</h3></body></html>
```

## Propfind (on the calendar, i don't answer the sync token here)

```
PROPFIND http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Content-Length: 181
Brief: t

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <C:getctag xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <A:sync-token/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 507
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:51 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <cs:getctag>669801837942</cs:getctag>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## Propfind (to find all the appointments)

### Request

```
PROPFIND host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Prefer: return=minimal
Depth: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Content-Length: 145
Brief: t

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <A:getcontenttype/>
    <A:getetag/>
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

### Response (there are for more appointments in the response, i show only the first here, but they look all the same with different hrefs)

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:54 GMT

2000
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop/>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/0075712608923743A35868DB6A589A31.ics</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getetag>1241532994</d:getetag>
        <d:getcontenttype>text/calendar</d:getcontenttype>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

## Report (to download all the appointments, again leaving out the other hrefs)

### Request

```
REPORT http://host:9998/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host:9998
Authorization: Basic bW5iam5ia2tqaHZmOm1oZ2o=
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Language: de-de
Content-Length: 7677
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: iOS/8.3 (12F69) dataaccessd/1.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<B:calendar-multiget xmlns:B="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
  <A:prop xmlns:A="DAV:">
    <A:getetag/>
    <B:calendar-data/>
    <C:created-by xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <C:updated-by xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <B:schedule-tag/>
  </A:prop>
  <A:href xmlns:A="DAV:">/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/50EAF942E0AB35A1B81792F7AAB6027E.ics</A:href>
</B:calendar-multiget>
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PROPFIND, PUT, REPORT
DAV: 1, 3, extended-mkcol, addressbook, access-control, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:25:58 GMT
Content-Length: 58259

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cal="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/.well-known/caldav/DEVELOPMENT/calendars/Robert%20Glaser/Alle%20Termine/50EAF942E0AB35A1B81792F7AAB6027E.ics</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getetag>1447948122</d:getetag>
        <cal:calendar-data>BEGIN:VCALENDAR&#13;
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN&#13;
VERSION:2.0&#13;
PRODID:-//DE/RND/DAV/CALDAV &#13;
BEGIN:VEVENT&#13;
DTSTAMP:20151215T082555Z&#13;
CLASS:PUBLIC&#13;
DESCRIPTION:&#13;
DTSTART:20151120T070000Z&#13;
DTEND:20151120T073000Z&#13;
SUMMARY:NeuerMehrTeilnehmerTermin&#13;
TRANSP:OPAQUE&#13;
ATTENDEE;CN=Robert Glaser;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:robert.glaser@web.de&#13;
RESOURCES:Audi A6&#13;
UID:50EAF942E0AB35A1B81792F7AAB6027E&#13;
CREATED:20151119T154839Z&#13;
LAST-MODIFIED:20151119T154839Z&#13;
END:VEVENT&#13;
END:VCALENDAR&#13;
</cal:calendar-data>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

After this, there are 4 more REPORT requests to get all the appointments.
Afterwards, there is a propfind request in the root directory of the host which i can't post because of the 30.000 characters limit. I can't answer this request since it doesn't reach my servlet.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The requests and responses; It's needed!

Comment: I added the entire communication, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my notes:

1. The entire caldav server being *under* `.well-known` is weird. The `.well-known` path is meant to just redirect to the real location. It *shouldn't* break, but it's possible.
2. In general it's a good thing to avoid percent-encoding in urls, such as your principal path. Again, it shouldn't be an issue, but I have seen clients trip up.
3. Your etags need to be surrounded by double quotes (also in the d:etag elements).

But I think the real culprit is that you don't support either the sync-token or the ctag. Client's *should* work fine without them, but the reality that I've seen is that some don't. I feel that this is the most likely problem, because the issue you describe has to do with syncing after the initial sync. Virtually any client will use the ctag (and many now use the sync-token) to figure out if anything changed in a collection.

Comment: I did all of them but still didn't help. To 2: I had a client on Android who failed to sync because of spaces in the url. Anyway, i don't use any characters anymore, who would need encoding. I am supporting the ctag but only on calendar collections. Can't support it on any other collection for now. I am answering the propfind request in the root path now same way as a propfind in the well-known path. iOS syncs twice now and the appointments stay but disappear during the next sync. Also editing doesn't work. But for the moment, I can't give any more time to this iOS specific strange behaviour.

Comment: Are your `UID`s and uri's stable between syncs? Another silly thing I noticed is that we also first encoded `\r` as `&#13;`, but this broke _some_ client (don't know which), so we stopped doing this as well.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there's a possbibility if there's simply one broken event in one of the calendars. Messing everything else up. And do you support `calendar-query`? It's a bit weird that there's no calendar-query request in any of the things you posted.

Comment: Yes my UIDs and UIRs are stable. I also tried it with a calendar, which has only one simple event. Same behaviour. Yes, I support calendar-query. I also support some of the filters like the timerange-filter but iOS doesn't seem to use it for some reason. Many other clients use it with sucess.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas :( but I have two more: using XCode while your iPad is hooked up you *might* be able to see some log messages from the Calendar client. Lastly, I think i would at this point compare your xml with a working server's xml... there must be some critical difference :/ Sorry

Comment: `<cal:comp name="VTIMEZONE"/>` does not belong in supported-calendar-component-set.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Logging the communication between the iPad and Owncloud (which runs in a vm on my host maschine) exceeds my linux proxy config skills and using Xcode would require a vm with MacOs. Atm, I don't have time for either. I removed the VTIMEZONE from the supported-calendar-component-set. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Today, i could finally fix the error. In the very first request, ios asks for the principal-**URL** and i answered with the principal-**url**. The last part of this tagname has to be written in uppercases in order to be recognized by iOS. It uses the URL to make one (from my opinion pointless) request to the principal after the sync.